# How to read Steam play time hours when they are in decimal format?

Tags: steam

In Steam the play time of a person is displayed in a decimal formatted number such as 0.5 hours or 21.9 hours. what is the significance of the number after the decimal point? And how should these times be read in the usual hours and minutes format?

Comment: Any comments on the down votes would be appreciated as it will help me to better explain my question in the future. Also consider putting a comment for your down voted in the future for other users.

Comment: you asked a **very basic** math question that is only very tangentially related to Steam. Needing someone to tell you that 0.5 is a half suggests you didn't put the effort in to thinking about the question for even 0.016 hours. That is why I down voted your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a simple math problem that has nothing to do with gaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to calculate the minutes from the decimal part via this calculation:

```
60 * [Decimal part]
```

So for your examples:

```
0.5 hours: 60 * 0.5 = 30 minutes
21.9 hours: 60 * 0.9 = 54 minutes (21 hours, 54 minutes in total)
```

Why they don't just put it in hours and minutes, I have no idea! Seems a bit strange really, especially then you have under 2 hours playtime on a game and it reports that in minutes only.

Comment: For me it is coming up as 60 / 0.5 = 120, 60 / 0.9 = 66.66

Comment: You mean 60 * [Decimal part], it's not a division

Comment: D'oh! I know what I meant and the answers were right, just my working was a little lacking!

Answer (score 6):

You multiply the decimal with 60.

21.9 hours = 21 hours and 54 minutes (60 * 0.9)

6.2 hours = 6 hours and 12 minutes (60 * 0.2)